# When will the Java VM support the Garbage First (G1) Collector for Linux ARM?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, arm, jvm-hotspot, g1gc

I am currently developing project which involves running a system on ARM, using java as the main execution language. Unfortunately Java 7 VM does not support the G1 gc for ARM boards, but I have not found anything about G1 support on ARM in Java 8.
When building a system which needs to respond very consistently and fast, is having a garbage collector a potential problem. I try to tune CMS gc and i get bad results. Young generation pauses is about 50-100 ms.

Comment: You would need to ask Oracle. I suspect that ARM support for G1 is not high on their list. Perhaps Java 9 will have it.  If you want faster, more consistent latencies, you could use a fast Intel processor. I would not expect G1 to be much faster than your young generation pauses. It is the old gen pauses which should be better.

Comment: depending on the workload g1 might make different generation sizing tradeoffs though which could result in shorter young gen pauses. but that's not something one should bet on before trying it.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/embedded/jdk-arm-8u6/index.html), the G1 collector has been available for the embedded ARM version of Java since Java 1.8.0u6.